# Select2 search box value is posted on form submit even value does not match

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

**Issue:**

**While pressing enter after searching in select2 search box the text box is getting populated with the search value (and the same is posted on form submit) even the search value does not match.**

During Search:

[image]

After Pressing Enter:

[image]

I am using select2 (`select2.full.js` version `Select2 4.0.6-rc.1`) with razor view.

HTML:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PartModel.AccountId, Model.PartModel.AccountList, "-- Select --", new { @class = "form-control search select2picker" })
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).find('.select2picker').select2({
        tags: true,
});
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't match? What you type abcd has the result of abcd as well.

Comment: It means the drop down does not contain 'abcd'.

Comment: Remove `tags:true` from Javascript